# Unrecognized font family Ionicons dont work on IOS

Tags: react-native

I have tried too many different ways but still don't work.
In Android works but not in iOS.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In your App.js file or your starting file
Add `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'`
then `Icon.loadFont();`